# Python: How do you get a programme to prompt the user a certian fixed amount of times for a user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, passwords, prompt

In the programme the user must enter a password, if he gets it wrong the programme will prompt him 2 more times and if he does not get right those 2 times the programme will expire. How do I go about doing this. This is my programme so far...

```
password=input("Enter password:")
while password != 'cat': 
    print ("password is wrong, try it again")
    password= input ("Enter your password:")

print ("Password correct be happy")
```

Comment: put it in a loop. if a proper answer is received, break out of the loop. if the loop expires without a proper answer, then do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import sys
max_tries = 3; current_tries = 0
password=input("Enter password:")
while password != 'cat': 
    if current_tries > max_tries:
        print "too many tries"
        sys.exit(0)
    print ("password is wrong, try it again")
    password= input ("Enter your password:")
    current_tries +=1


print ("Password correct be happy")
```

Comment: this will give too many retries message even if user gets last attempt right ... instead you should put the check at the top

Answer (score 1):

#### The charitable programmer

```
for trial in range(3):
    print ("Attempt no.",trial, end=" ")
    passw = input('.  Enter password > ')
    if passw == 'cat' : break
else:
    passw = 'cat'
```

Yes, also the humble `for` loop has an `else` clause: ["Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement."](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Answer (score 0):

```
max_tries = 3
password = None
for i in range(max_tries):
    password = input("Enter Password:")
    if password == "cat": break
if password != "cat": 
    print ("ERROR TOO MANY TRIES!")
else:
    print ("You Win!")
```

is a simple way to do it ...